# Android assets timestamp

Tags: android, timestamp, assets

I noticed that the timestamp of assets files is set to the build date. How to preserve the timestamp of files in the assets folder when the apk is built?
And is it possible to retrieve this timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

You might try to get hold of the `.apk` file and try to "unzip" it with the help of a `ZipInputStream` in order to get at the entries.

But as you say this will give you the timestamps of the build date (probably because the build chain is copying the files into a target directory before zipping it up).

What you could do is to add a file into assets, which holds your "desired timestamp" as content and which you could then open in your app and read the timestamp from.